# angular js template logic to remove repeater item

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a repeater that looks like

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="obj in data">
  {{obj.value}}
</ion-item>
```

which displays an item list of the numbers 1 through 10. When an odd number shows up I want that particular item to be hidden. Is this something I can do within the view it's self? Regardless what's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to control your data set in your controller:

```
$scope.ProId = "";    
$scope.HideOdd = function (){
        -- create a function to hide DATA
}
```

and on your ion tag ad `ng-hide="HideOdd"`